# laravel 5 middleware with parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm an absolute beginner in Laravel 5.

I've created a middleware class called BeforeMiddleware the blueprint of that class is below.

```
class BeforeMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if($request->user()->hasRole($role)){
            return redirect('/pensions');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

registered in kernel.php as

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        'role' => 'App\Http\Middleware\BeforeMiddleware',
    ];
```

User model is below

```
class User extends Model {
    public function hasRole($name)
    {
        return ($this->role->name == $name) ? true : false;
    }

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role');
    }
}
```

and usage in routes.php is below.

```
Route:get('/reporting', [ 'middleware' => 'role:Owner', 'uses' => function(){
    return 'secret data only be viewable by the owners';
}]);
```

If I open that in the browser `/reporting` I get the following error.

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 776:
Class role:Owner does not exist
```

**HOWEVER** if I hard code `'Owner'` in middleware and remove the `$role` parameter and also removed it from routes which now looks like this.

BeforeMiddleware.php

```
class BeforeMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if($request->user()->hasRole('Owner')){
            return redirect('/pensions');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route:get('/reporting', [ 'middleware' => 'role', 'uses' => function(){
        return 'secret data only be viewable by the owners';
    }]);
```

it works as desired...

therefore my question is how to pass that parameter when using middleware to control routes

Any Idea?

Comment: What if you use `role:owner` in the route definition?

Comment: hello @Luceos did not get that ... can you elaborate ... I'm a newbie

Comment: you use `role:Owner` in your route definition, what happens when you use `role:owner`, perhaps it assumes you want to use a class if you write some letters in capitals.

Comment: thanks for your input @Luceos I've tried it both ways same error :(

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.1?

Comment: no @JakeOpena I'm using laravel 5

Answer (score 2):

If you read carefully the [Middleware Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware), you will notice this line

> Middleware parameters may be specified when defining the route by separating the middleware name and parameters with a :. Multiple parameters should be delimited by commas

So in your case if your middleware class is called `BeforeMiddleware`, the first part of middleware definition should be `before` then `:`, and after that you can define your route parameters, separated with comma, like this:

```
Route:get('/reporting', [ 'middleware' => 'before:Owner', 'uses' => function(){
    return 'secret data only be viewable by the owners';
}]);
```

Comment: this feature is available on laravel 5.1

Comment: any way to pass it inside the Route Class constructor when we use `$this->middleware('name_of_middleware')` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Laravel 5.0, I suggest to just create separate middlewares for your roles.

**Kernel.php**

```
'owner' => 'App\Http\Middleware\OwnerMiddleware',
```

**OwnerMiddleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->user()->hasRole('Owner')){
        return redirect('/pensions');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Then in **routes.php**

```
Route:get('/reporting', [ 'middleware' => 'owner', 'uses' => function(){
    return 'secret data only be viewable by the owners';
}]);
```

Comment: thanks @JakeOpena, I know it would work but this is just an example.. there are routes where i would give access to more than one roles... if you know what i'm sayin